# Redirecionamento htaccess se extensão e pasta não corresponderem

Tags: htaccess

Quero fazer com que redirecione para o meu domínio, se não for um arquivo .php ou determinadas pastas. O php eu consegui:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.(php)$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.exemplo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Feito,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.(php)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(pasta1|pasta2)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.exemplo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Isto é um complemento à pergunta ou é uma resposta ? Se é uma resposta convem explicar como o problema está a ser resolvido e o que aconteceu para que assim seja.